# Magento 1 to Magento 2 | Data-Migration-Tool | Integrity Check + Offset

Tags: magento, migration, e-commerce, data-migration, database-integrity

I would like to migrate data from Magento 1 to Magento 2 with Data-Migration-Tool.
(I’m working on a local windows machine with wamp)

`Magento 1 —> v1.6.0.0`

`Magento 2 —> v2.1.2`

I’ve got many errors during the data migration. (Ok for the settings migration)

```
C:\wamp64\www\magento_2.1.2>php bin/magento migrate:data C:/wamp64/www/magento_2.1.2/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.6.0.0/config.xml
[2016-11-30 10:05:51][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: EAV Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2016-11-30 10:05:51][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2016-11-30 10:05:51][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Map Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[0;31m[2016-11-30 10:05:54][ERROR]: Source documents are not mapped: api2_acl_attribute,api2_acl_role,api2_acl_rule,api2_acl_user,atos_log_request,atos_log_response,caroussel,catalog_product_entity_group_price,colorswatch_attribute_settings,colorswatch_images,customer_flowpassword,giftpromo,hipay_rule,magemonkey_api_debug,magemonkey_bulksync_export,magemonkey_bulksync_import,magemonkey_ecommerce360,payline_contract,payline_contract_status,payline_nx_fees,permission_block,permission_variable,xtcore_config_data,xtento_orderexport_destination,xtento_orderexport_log,xtento_orderexport_profile,xtento_orderexport_profile_history,zizio_groupsale,zizio_groupsale_sales_order[0m
[0;31m[2016-11-30 10:05:54][ERROR]: Destination documents are not mapped: shipping_tablerate[0m
[0;31m[2016-11-30 10:05:54][ERROR]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: catalogrule. Fields: sub_is_enable,sub_simple_action,sub_discount_amount[0m
[0;31m[2016-11-30 10:05:54][ERROR]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: catalogrule_product. Fields: sub_simple_action,sub_discount_amount[0m
[0;31m[2016-11-30 10:05:54][ERROR]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily. Fields: product_type_id[0m
[0;31m[2016-11-30 10:05:54][ERROR]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly. Fields: product_type_id[0m
[0;31m[2016-11-30 10:05:54][ERROR]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly. Fields: product_type_id[0m
[0;33m[2016-11-30 10:05:54][WARNING]: Mismatch of data types. Source document: rating_option_vote. Fields: remote_ip_long[0m
[0;33m[2016-11-30 10:05:54][WARNING]: Mismatch of data types. Source document: sendfriend_log. Fields: ip[0m
[0;33m[2016-11-30 10:05:54][WARNING]: Mismatch of data types. Destination document: rating_option_vote. Fields: remote_ip_long[0m
[0;33m[2016-11-30 10:05:54][WARNING]: Mismatch of data types. Destination document: sendfriend_log. Fields: ip[0m
[2016-11-30 10:05:54][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Url Rewrite Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2016-11-30 10:05:54][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Log Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2016-11-30 10:05:54][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Ratings Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2016-11-30 10:05:54][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: ConfigurablePrices step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2016-11-30 10:05:54][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2016-11-30 10:05:54][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Tier Price Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2016-11-30 10:05:54][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec

[Migration\Exception]
Integrity Check failed

migrate:data [-r|--reset] config

C:\wamp64\www\magento_2.1.2>
```

So my question is it normal errors ?

Do you think it is only extensions tables / fields ?

I would like to keep only source database (customers, orders, etc..) without extensions modifications.

I need help.
Thanks very much !!!

Comment: http://www.ipragmatech.com/magento2-migration-guide/

Comment: Thanks :D I'will have a look

Comment: If  ignore all errors I get this one :

Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in C:\wamp64\www\magento_2.1.2\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\src\Migration\Step\Eav\Data.php on line 527

Comment: This is the line 527 in Data.php :

$attributeSetGroups[$record->getValue('attribute_set_id')][$attributeGroupCode]

Comment: If I try another time to migrate (after undefined offset error), I get this new error :

[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicata du champ '1-Migration_Default' pour la clef 'EAV_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ENTITY_TYPE_ID_ATTRIBUTE_SET_NAME'